# Magento "include(Profiler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Autoload.php"

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.2.1, varien-autoload

I tried moving a project to another server but after I copy all the files and the database and try to access the new server I get the warning:

> `include(DOMDocument.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/projectname/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94`

It makes it imposible to access either the frontend or the backend.
The magento version for the project on the old server is 1.8.1.0 and the magento version for the project on the new server is 1.9.2.1.
Maybe someone else encountered this error and can give an advice on where to start.

Comment: Hi Nicoleta, welcome to MageSE. Just an obvious question; did you set file rights and owners correctly?

Comment: Hi Sander. Yes, the rights are set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the Dom library isn't installed on the server.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php for more info